# How to select an option in a dropdown list using WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS

Tags: perl, phantomjs, mechanize

I am trying to select an option that has no value using [WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS)

I have tried both methods below:

```
$mech->set_fields($name, $value);
$mech->field($name, $value);
```

This is the select element I am trying to select from:

```
<select class="calendarDateInput" id="enddate_Day_ID" onchange="enddate_Object.changeDay(this)">
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
     <option>3</option>
         ...
</select>
```

I have not been able to select any of the options. Apparently WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS does not have the select method.  I am still a noob in Perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this.  I am closing the question because I found alternative to doing this, and the PhantomJS is being deprecated and its successor is Chrome.